# Symbol Barcode Reader on_read issue

Tags: event-handling, barcode-scanner, .net-cf-3.5

I have a Moto Mc9096 device, EDMK SDK, VS2008 etc all of the prereq's

I'm having an issue where once I've scanned a barcode it constantly repeats the event. normally when this happens its a flag or status needs changing but there are no obvious settings to stop it reading again.

code below

```
private void Barcode_Read(object sender, ReaderData readerdata)
{
    if (readerdata.Text != null)
    {
        if (readerdata.Text == "abc")
        {
             MessageBox.Show(readerdata.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Notes
I've tried

```
    bar.Dispose();
    bar.Reader.Actions.Flush();
    bar.ReaderData.Dispose() ;
```

with no success. the EnabledScanner is set on form load and off during form close.

My expectation was when the user scans a barcode it fires the read event once.
but it constantly fires after the users first scan.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the aimType property, by default it should be AIM_TYPE_TRIGGER but other settings allow a single trigger pull to perform multiple scans (AIM_TYPE_CONTINUOUS_READ) so perhaps that has been changed.

You should have some samples installed by the SDK at file:///C:/Users/Public/Motorola%20EMDK%20for%20.NET/v2.9/SampLauncher2008.htm (by default) that show best practice.